# IIS 7 filling disk with millions of certificate files

Tags: iis, iis-7, ssl-certificate, asp.net

I've got an ASP.NET website running on IIS 7.  Using PA File Sight, I've proven that it is creating 2 to 3 new files in the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys folder every minute.

PA File Sight shows the user as IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool and the process as w3wp.exe, so I know it's my website and IIS 7.

There are millions of files in that folder now (can't open in Explorer, even directory listing from command prompt takes hours).  The disk is about to run out of space and the server will be hosed :(

Does anyone know WHY?

I've gone into the Machine Key setting of IIS and disabled (unchecked) "Automatically generate at runtime" and "generate a unique key for each application" for both validation key and decryption key, but that hasn't helped.

The server is Windows 2008 R2, and has all of the latest patches.

I figure I'm about a week or two from running out of space.  Very anxious to hear suggestions!

One last note, the server does support SSL connections, but they are very rare (very little of the site is protected/sensitive).

Comment: Does the time of a certificate file creation correlate with any particular request in the IIS log file?

Comment: That's a brilliant idea Andrew!

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be a problem using the JdSoft.Apns.Notifications to send Apple push notifications (not sure if my usage problem, or something in the component).

This component is deprecated in favor of [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/), so the problem is moot.